# SQL select where like using query string

Tags: mysql, sql

if i have these two complicated  query strings

```
 ALM_frmTopAlarmHistoryReport.aspx?strAlarmConnection=AlarmSystem
```

AND

```
 http://1.1.4.1/xyz/ALM_frmAlarmHistoryReport.aspx?ViewPDF=
 1&dtmStartDate={0}&dtmEndDate={1}& + '&lngAlarmGroup=' + 
 $('#ddlAlarmGroup').val() + '&lngProcessor=' + $('#ddlProcessor').val() + 
 '&intCategory=' + $('#ddlCategory').val()
```

how can i excuete a `select WHERE LIKE` condition 
i tried

```
 SELECT * FROM [tablename] WHERE string1 LIKE '%string2%'
```

and i got the following error

```
   Msg 103, Level 15, State 4, Line 1
   The identifier that starts with'%string2 ' is too long. Maximum length is 128.
```

any help will be very welcome thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use locate or instr instead:

```
select *
from tablename
where instr(string2, string1)  > 0
```